# R - subsetting a list

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and it would be a big help to find a way to do this.

I have a list of values(just one Column and around 16000 values) and I have to break this list up into smaller packets of 1000 values each. Then save each list as a csv file. 
Is there a way of doing this is R?

Thank you in advance,
Dgupta

Comment: Break your problem into smaller problems: (1) segmenting your list (2) looping over results or possibly applying a function to each segment (3) writing segments to .csv (in the loop or in the applied function).  Answers to each of these sub-problems are already easily found on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Dasgupta can you add a sample of your data to make it reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    data <- as.data.frame(list)
    groups <- split(1:nrow(data), ceiling(seq_along(1:nrow(data)/1000))
    for (i in 1:length(groups)){write.csv(data[groups[1,],file=paste(i,'csv'))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the vector up by using a colon symbol in the vector index.  For example:

```
> x <- c(10,20,30,40)
> x[1:2]

[1] 10 20
```

you can then write a vector to a csv by using the `write.csv()`function. One way to approach this is to write loop that gets 1000 items at a time from the vector and writes it to a csv.